# XP64 2 XP64 install software using WMI

Tags: windows, wmi

I try to install a .exe remote onto my gaming PC. I know the .exe exists but the call gives me an error.

```
C:\WINDOWS>wmic /node:"Spiele" /user:"Spielen" /password:"XXX" product call install true,"", "C:\setup.exe"
ERROR:
Code = 0x80041002
Description = Not found
Facility = WMI
C:\WINDOWS>
```

The location of the exe-File I Like to run is

```
c:\setup.exe
```

If I execute `bios get serialnumber` no such error message occour

```
C:\WINDOWS>wmic /node:"Spiele" /user:"Spielen" /password:"XXX" bios get serialnumber /value


SerialNumber=JVZSZS2



C:\WINDOWS>
```

### Maybe security issue

I tried `wmic product list` who should realy give me a list of installed programs. That there is a error-message let me think it is a security issue:

```
C:\WINDOWS>wmic product list
Node - E
ERROR:
Code = 0x80041010
Description = Invalid class
Facility = WMI



C:\WINDOWS>
```

Comment: can you show the location of the file you are looking to run? Also, are you certain the username and password are present on the machine you are running the file on.

Comment: @Stese I am absolutly sure the username and password is correct and the file exists.

Comment: does that user have access to that file in that location? Maybe move it to C:\users\<user>\documents and see if it works there.

Comment: @Stese I moved that file to  `C:\Documents and Settings\Spielen\My Documents\setup.exe`, modified the command but it still gives the same error message.

Comment: @Stese Since `wmic product list` returns the same error on the "Spiele"-pc non-remote, I think it is a security issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I know the .exe exists but the call gives me an error.

> ```
> C:\WINDOWS>wmic /node:"Spiele" /user:"Spielen" /password:"XXX" product call install true,"", "C:\setup.exe"
> ERROR:
> Code = 0x80041002
> Description = Not found
> Facility = WMI
> ```

This usually means that the Windows Installer provider is not installed.

> WMI is installed by default on all Windows desktop and server
>   platforms. However, certain WMI providers may or may not be installed,
>   depending on the OS release and configuration. For example, the SNMP
>   provider is not enabled by default, and **the Windows Installer provider
>   (MSI provider) is not installed by default on 64-bit operating
>   systems**. For more information about the availability of a specific
>   provider, see [WMI Providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bg126473).

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source [Operating System Availability of WMI Components - Windows applications | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/operating-system-availability-of-wmi-components)

> The provider is an optional component on Windows 64-bit desktop and server operating systems, but can be installed through the Control panel.

Source [Windows Installer Provider | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/msiprov/windows-installer-provider)

> 1. Open the Control Panel.
> 2. Go to Add or Remove Programs.
> 3. Select Add/Remove Windows Components.
> 4. Double-click Management and Monitoring Tools.
>
>    This action opens a secondary window displaying additional
>      selections.
> 5. Select WMI Windows Installer Provider check box.
> 6. Click OK to return to the Windows Components Wizard window.
> 7. Click Next.
>
> You might be asked for the Windows installation CD to complete this
>   process.

Source [Enable WMI Windows Installer provider | ServiceNow Docs](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-it-operations-management/page/administer/orchestration_activities/task/t_EnableWMIWindowsInstallProvider.html)